# Кодировка кириллицы mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, кириллица

После обновления текстовых полей БД в Mysql кириллица отображается в виде экранированных кодов

```
\&#1050;\&#1088;\&#1072;\&#1089;\&#1085;\&#1072;\&#1103; \&#1088;\&#1077;\&#1082;\&#1072;
```

При этом, если выводить ее в html из базы отображается она нормально "Красная река".

При этом, если выполнять запрос из того же php как текст (заменить все переменные на их значения), то в Mysql попадает нормальная кириллица и мы там видим "Красная река".

При этом, если из того же php выводить данные базы, то снова выходит нормальная "Красная река".

Сравнение поля в Mysql настроено на utf8_general_ci
В начале php задаю "SET NAMES utf8"
Кодировка файла php UTF-8

В заголовке страницы вывода, которую формирует php стоит

```
\<meta charset='utf-8'>.
```

Хочется, собственно, чтобы в поле Mysql отображались русские буквы после выполнения запроса апдейта из php.

Comment: Где у вас так отображается? Вы уверены, что вы при записи в базу записывали настоящий текст, а не экранированный?

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе разобрался. Эффект связан с тем, что в переменной у меня все это время был не текст, а html коды символов. Поэтому я и не мог понять, почему у меня везде нормальный текст кроме базы, потому что везде html код автоматически браузером заменялся на нормальные символы.

Для того, чтобы и в БД их копировать, нужно просто применить функцию html_entity_decode без вторых параметров.